# Export data to a text file from a SQL Server table with changing columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, pivot, export

I have created a Pivot table using columns passed in from a variable.  This variable is set based on a flag in another table, so the name and number of columns can change month-to-month.  I need to be able to export this pivot to a delimited text file.  The pivot table is stored in a temp table ##PivotTable

I have tried to do this via SSMS, but the only way I know how to do this is to define a file connection manager, which needs set columns.  I also tried via sqlcmd, but that one exports extra information and spaces.

I am open to pretty much any process that would allow me to run this via a SQL Agent job on a monthly basis.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL server import and export wizard

Right  click on the database-->Tasks-->ExportData..

map your ##PivotTable.

[image]

Click next and set your source database (Select OLEDB provider for SQL Server)

Set a  file name for your file (e.g. d:\monthlyData\202006\MyFile.csv

*Select option copy data from one to more tables or views* -- do not use this option due the fact that your columns getting changed.

Select option  write a quarry
[image]

[image]

You can run this immediately or  save as SSIS package and reuse it using SQL job

Comment: I need to be able to run the export automatically every month.  Even if I save this job, I would have the same issue as with defining the Connection in SSMS - it will be defined as the table is today and not automatically change when there are additional columns.

Comment: @Islandz You can convert your pviot table to another temptable (e.g ##ExportTable) and new table should contain one column and it should have delimited string data, Then you can export data directly out for that table SQL Job. XML output would be the ideal way to get these type of data ( but its not your requirement).

Comment: @Islandz  try select * from ##pivottable  source quarry method

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to use dynamic SQL like found [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/).

Comment: I already have the pivot table working (including dynamically getting the columns).  What I am looking for now is how to export that pivot automatically on a monthly schedule without needing to change anything each run.